# How a PanResponder can become primary

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have 2 `PanResponder` in 2 different views.

```
<Animated.View
    style={leftRightStyle}
    {...this.panLeftRightResponder.panHandlers}
>
    <Animated.View
        style={bottomTopStyle}
        {...this.panBottomTopResponder.panHandlers}
    >
        {this.props.children}
    </Animated.View>
</Animated.View>
```

The first `PanResponder` should detect a swipe left and right, while the second `PanResponder` detects a swipe from bottom to top.

My issue is when the first one is granted, the second `PanResponder` becomes inaccessible and can never be granted.

Is there a way for the second one to be accessible and terminate the first one?

Thanks